# Consistent variable colours in factoextra across plots

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, pca

I am trying to keep my plots with consistent variable colours while using the `factoextra` library to plot PCA results. Reproducible example below:

```
data("decathlon2")
df <- decathlon2[1:23, 1:10]
library("FactoMineR")
res.pca <- PCA(df,  graph = FALSE)
get_eig(res.pca)

# Contributions of variables to PC1
fviz_contrib(res.pca, choice = "var", axes = 1, top = 10)
# Contributions of variables to PC2
fviz_contrib(res.pca, choice = "var", axes = 2, top = 10)
```

I would like the plot for PC1 and PC2 to have a color palette with 10 colours which is identical across plots (i.e. x100m will be red in both). However, in my actual data-set I have 15 explanatory variables which seems to be above the limit for color brewer so there are 2 problems:

1. How to maintain consistent colour scheme
2. Be able to utilise 15 colors

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use one of the colourbrewer palettes? The default colour scale used by ggplot2 (see `?scale_colour_hue`) creates an evenly spaced range of colours on the colour wheel, so it can handle any number of colours. These colours would also be consistent as long as you have the same number of explanatory variables.

Comment: Not necessarily (regarding having to use colourbrewer). The problem is the variables displayed aren't consistent - as in, it's the top 10 contributors each time so they will not always be the same. However, I suppose one simple-ish solution is to display all 15 every time and then use scale_colour_hue (but then I don't know if it's consistent if the order changes I will look it up now).

Comment: Okay, I think I see what you mean. Let me think of something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I assume you already know you need to add `fill = "name"` to the `fviz_contrib()` call; otherwise the bars will default to `fill = "steelblue"`.)

You can define the palette manually, such that each variable corresponds to the same colour.

To simulate the problem using the example in the question, suppose we only want to show the top 7, when there are 10 variables all together:

```
# naive way with 7-color palette applied to different variables
fviz_contrib(res.pca, choice = "var", fill = "name", color = "black", axes = 1, top = 7)
fviz_contrib(res.pca, choice = "var", fill = "name", color = "black", axes = 2, top = 7)
```

[image: plot1]

We can create a palette using `hue_pal()` from the `scales` package, for 10 different colours (one for each column of `df`).

*(You can also use palettes such as `rainbow()` / `heat.colors()` / etc. from the base `grDevices` package. I find their default colour range to be rather intense, though, with a tendency to be overly glaring for a bar chart.)*

```
mypalette <- scales::hue_pal()(ncol(df))
names(mypalette) <- colnames(df)

# optional: see what each color corresponds to
ggplot(data.frame(x = names(mypalette),
                  y = 1,
                  fill = mypalette)) +
  geom_tile(aes(x = x, y = y, fill = fill), color = "black") +
  scale_fill_identity() +
  coord_equal()
```

[image: palette]

Use `scale_fill_manual()` with the self-defined palette on each chart:

```
fviz_contrib(res.pca, choice = "var", fill = "name", color = "black", axes = 1, top = 7) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = mypalette)
fviz_contrib(res.pca, choice = "var", fill = "name", color = "black", axes = 2, top = 7) +
  scale_fill_manual(values = mypalette)
```

[image: plot2]